# Where do you use typescript Awaited<T> in async functions?

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I am calling an asynchronous function that calls another function that returns a Promise.

I want my final variable `csvRows` to be of `csvRow[]` type. Instead, I am getting `Promise<csvRow[]>` type returned. I read that `Awaited<T>` can unwrap this, but I'm confused on how to use it. What function do I use it in? The one returning the original promise, or the function using async/await syntax? Somewhere else entirely?

The defined type I want the variable `csvRows` to be:

```
export type csvRow = { [level: string]: string }
```

The code causing issues:

```
const parseFile = (file) => {
  return new Promise<csvRow[]>((resolve, reject) => {
    Papa.parse(file, {
      header: true,
      delimter: ',',
      download: true,
      skipEmptyLines: true,
      complete: (a: csvType) => {
        resolve(a.data)
      },
      error(err) {
        reject(err)
      }
    })
  })
}


export const useTimeSeriesData = async (): Promise<csvRow[]> => {
  let csvRows = await parseFile('/path/to/file')
  return csvRows
}


const csvRows = useTimeSeriesData()
```

In the code above there's a line in `parseFile` using `csvType`, that's defined like this:

```
export type csvType = {
  data: csvRow[]
}
```

I've tried using `Awaited` in the various functions, but have had no luck. This is the error I get when trying to use my `csvRows` variable later in my code:

> Argument of type 'Promise<csvRow[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'csvRow[]'.
> Type 'Promise<csvRow[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'csvRow[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.ts(2345)

Comment: Types don't affect runtime behavior, and you can't extract the value from a `Promise` without `await`ing it or using `then`.  Nothing you do with  `Awaited<T>` will change that, so the error is correct and to be expected.  If you're trying to figure out how to use async functions there are almost certainly existing questions that explain that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably trying to `await` the call because it is asynchronous. You can just:

```js
const csvRows: csvRow[] = await useTimeSeriesData();
```

To answer your original question on how to use `Awaited` type... It can be helpful when creating types from function. For example:

```js
type CsvRowsReturnType = ReturnType<typeof useTimeSeriesData>; // Promise<csvRow[]>
type CsvRowsType = Awaited<CsvRowsReturnType>; // csvRow[]
```

[tsplayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=59&pln=11&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAxgzgNwEoHsDuUC8UDeUDaANhAhIQFxRzABOAlgHYDmAupdfc1AL4BQvEAB5gUNYLBQNqUAK5wIAFToBbCAGUI9CHAAiAQ2B6sUPXBAMYUABQBKSgAUaKZXXkAeeMnT4WAPiz%20OLxQUAD0oVAAdNFQaAAWBiSaUABUocFQNBDAMjQMBCwA3Lx8vOFQICgyUAmkUMAoJmh6dMAANFAARhAwenLQrVCuUI7OrhC8MJLSnqhocJSz3izGes2D-UqqGlq6Bnq2-OWGhADWjCadVeKgkHDRkby30ADCiHNwSNm5DArg0Ngvjk8n9IG5nigAGayeRbdSaOjafSGXyFMIRUYudxLNA%20XxPf5QN5eeaggFQACC62AEAAJm5iR8gT8yaj0bB3ssgA)